# how to show records that don't have custom meta value

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, post-meta, pre-get-posts

Running `pre_get_posts`, I want to order the items by a custom meta value. The problem is that by default this doesn't exist. Only if a user performs a certain action does the meta key/value get added.

That being said, even if they don't ever click on the item itself, I would like it to be displayed. Basically the order is the number of clicks an items has received.

So, the most clicked item should be first and the items that haven't been clicked yet should be last, but they are not showing up at all.

```
function show_user_counts( $query ) {

  if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_tax('my_category')) {
    $query->set('meta_key', 'number_clicks' );
    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value'  );
    $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'show_user_counts', 9999);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the most clicked item should be first and the items that haven't been clicked yet should be last, but they are not showing up at all

They aren't showing up because your posts query is only selecting posts that have the `number_clicks` meta, and thus MySQL ignores all posts which do not have that meta.

So what you need is two meta query clauses *with an `OR` relation* — the 1st clause will select posts that have the `number_clicks` meta, whereas the 2nd clause will select posts **without** that meta.

And for that, you can instead use the `meta_query` arg, so in your code, just replace the `$query->set('meta_key', 'number_clicks' );` with:

```php
$query->set( 'meta_query', array(
    'relation'       => 'OR',

    'number_clicks'  => array( // 1st clause
        'key' => 'number_clicks',
    ),

    'number_clicks2' => array( // 2nd clause
        'key'     => 'number_clicks',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
    ),
) );
```

Then to sort the results by the `number_clicks` value, set the `orderby` to the array key (`number_clicks2`) for the 2nd clause above, i.e. `$query->set( 'orderby', 'number_clicks2' )`.

And note that the 2nd clause above uses `NUMERIC` as the `type` so that MySQL will convert the meta value to a number which then gives us the correct numerical sorting.

- Remember that meta values are stored as strings/text in the database, hence for example (these individual values — ) `10, 4, 1, 3, 2` will be sorted into `1, 10, 2, 3, 4` instead of `1, 2, 3, 4, 10`. Because that's what happen when the values are sorted as strings.
- So actually, you should've used `$query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' )` so that the meta value is converted to a number prior to sorting. But now you no longer need to use that because the meta value type is already set in the 2nd clause above.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks Sally!